# C++ Struct in recursion return nullptr ？

Tags: c++, struct

I was solving the [leetcode 106](https://leetcode.com/problems/construct-binary-tree-from-inorder-and-postorder-traversal/). I know how to use recursion in this problem. But i am confused about the inialization of a struct. The passed version is as follows:

```
/**
 * Definition for a binary tree node.
 * struct TreeNode {
 *     int val;
 *     TreeNode *left;
 *     TreeNode *right;
 *     TreeNode(int x) : val(x), left(NULL), right(NULL) {}
 * };
 */
class Solution {
public:
    TreeNode* buildTree(vector<int>& inorder, vector<int>& postorder) {
        int len = inorder.size();
        if (inorder.empty() && postorder.empty())
            return nullptr;
        return buildTree(inorder, 0, len - 1, postorder, 0, len - 1);
    }

    int getIndex (vector<int> order, int key)
    {
        int i = 0;
        for(int n: order)
        {
            if (n == key)
                break;
            i++;
        }
        return i;
    }

    TreeNode* buildTree(vector<int>& inorder, int is, int ie, vector<int>& postorder, int ps, int pe)
    {
        if (is > ie || ps > pe)
            return nullptr;
        TreeNode* root = new TreeNode(postorder[pe]);
        int index = getIndex(inorder, postorder[pe]);
        //cout<< index <<" "<<postorder[pe]<< endl;
        root->left = buildTree(inorder, is, index - 1, postorder, ps, ps + index - is - 1);
        root->right = buildTree(inorder, index + 1, ie, postorder, pe - ie + index,pe - 1);
        return root;
    }
};
```

Then i changed another way to inialize the struct, as follows:

```
TreeNode* buildTree(vector<int>& inorder, int is, int ie, vector<int>& postorder, int ps, int pe)
{
    if (is > ie || ps > pe)
        return nullptr;
    struct TreeNode root(postorder[pe]);
    int index = getIndex(inorder, postorder[pe]);
    //cout<< index <<" "<<postorder[pe]<< endl;
    root.left = buildTree(inorder, is, index - 1, postorder, ps, ps + index - is - 1);
    root.right = buildTree(inorder, index + 1, ie, postorder, pe - ie + index,pe - 1);
    //cout<< root.val << " " << root.right << " " << root.left <<endl;
    return &root;
}
```

this version is always return the nullptr. So what is wrong and what is the difference between the two ways?

Comment: You need to enable compiler warnings.

Comment: `return &root;` is returning the address of a local variable. You can't do that as it goes out of scope when the function ends. [Can a local variable's memory be accessed outside its scope?](//stackoverflow.com/q/6441218)

Comment: OK，now i know that the new keyword malloc a persistent memory during the recursion process while the local struct variable destroyed. Thanks a lot!

Comment: @liuqi "_now i know that the new keyword malloc_" Don't use `malloc` in C++, because it doesn't invoke constructors.

Comment: @Algirdas Preidžius Thanks! I will remember that and avoid such mistakes!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `new` operator will dynamically allocate memory that will be stored on *the heap*. The second version that doesn't work simply creates the variable and stores it on the stack. After that function call is finished all of the information will be popped off the stack and anything that was stored at those memory locations will no longer be considered valid. i.e. saying `return &root` returns an invalid address after that function is done.

Answer (score 0):

The difference you made is that you've created a [Dangling Pointer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dangling_pointer). In short, you should not return the address (by reference) of a local variable because local variables gets deallocated when they're out of scope. Instead, you should return a copy of `root` (by value). Hence, no `&` needed, but make sure you have a copy constructor if your tree data is not of primitive type (not `int`, `double`, ...etc)